# (cmd) Como descompactar arquivos de um .zip pelo cmd do Windows

Tags: windows, cmd

Preciso de ajuda para descompactar arquivos .mdf e .ldf que fica em um único arquivo .zip, preciso fazer isso pelo cmd do Windows.

Comment: Se você usar o 7zip esse vídeo pode te ajudar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLMJgnVKkFE.

O cara manda você baixar o arquivo desse link (http://www.7-zip.org/) e retirar o executável e a **.dll** para que funcione pelo CMD.

Comment: Boa noite, tem como fazer via bat híbrido c VBS, tens interesse na solução?  Basicamente eh um bat q gera um VBS para executar a descompactaçäo do arquivo.

Comment: Sim, eu tenho interesse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

> **Update** adicionado suporte para passagem argumento [%~1] argumento [%~2]

---

```bat
Un_Zipper.cmd %~1         %~2
Un_Zipper.cmd Arquivo.Zip Dive+\Pasta-DestinoX para descompactar Arquivo.Zip
```

---

> Uso com **"parâmetro/argumento"** para apontar a pasta de destino para descompactação
>
> <kbd>**`Un_Zipper.cmd "arquivo.zip" "c:\Pasta_de_destino"`**</kbd>

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> Se o %~2 não for informado, ele **descompacta na pasta** 
>    "%temp%\Nome_do_Zip_Sem_Extensão"
>
> Acredito que seja de boa pra vc editar de maneira que possa manusear os **arquivos/pastas** para seus respectivos **destinos** pós descompactação...

---

> <kbd>**[`Un_Zipper.cmd`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/369221/cmd-como-descompactar-arquivos-de-um-zip-pelo-cmd-do-windows)**</kbd>

---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & title 

color 9F & cls & cd /d "%~dp0" & mode 60,7 & set "_pping=pathping 127.1 -q 1 -p 100" & title <nul

if /i ".%~1/"=="./" set "_msg_err_= Use: %~nx0 Arquivo.Zip "c:\Pasta-destino" # Arquivo.Zip nao Informado ou Invalido " && goto :_3rr0_msg_:
if /i not "%~x1"==".zip" set "_msg_err_= Arquivo: %~nx1 Nao eh Valido # Use: %~nx0 Arquivo.Zip "c:\Pasta de destino"" && goto :_3rr0_msg_:
if /i ".%~2/"=="./" (set "_target_dir=%temp%\%~n1") else (set "_target_dir=%~2" & if not exist "%~2\" mkdir "%~2" || goto :_3rr0_msg_:)

if /i "!_msg_err_!./"=="./" set "_vbs_Un_Zipper_=%temp%\Un_Zipper.vbs" & type nul>"!_vbs_Un_Zipper_!"
set "_zip_File_=%~nx1" & set "_Zip_Folder_=!_target_dir!" & if /i not "!_Zip_File_:~-3!"=="zip" goto :_3rr0_msg_:
set "_Run_wScript_=start "" /w "%Windir%\System32\wscript.exe" "!_vbs_Un_Zipper_!" //nologo"

(rmdir /q /s "!_Zip_Folder_!" & !_pping! && mkdir "!_Zip_Folder_!" || mkdir "!_Zip_Folder_!") 2>nul >nul
!_pping! >nul && copy /y "%~f1" "!_Zip_Folder_!\!_zip_File_!" >nul & set "_Zip_File_=!_Zip_Folder_!\!_zip_File_!"

set _Zip_File=!_Zip_Folder_!\!_zip_File_!" & dir "!_Zip_Folder_!\*.zip" /b >nul 2>nul || >nul (
set _msg_err_= ERRO: Nao Encontrado !_zip_File_! " & goto :_3rr0_msg_:)

call :_write_vbs_: & !_pping! >nul & echo/ & echo/ & echo/  Descompactando: %~nx1... & !_Run_wScript_!
if "!%errorlevel%!" == "!0!" goto :eof || set "_msg_err_=Erro: Verique !_Zip_Folder_!\%~nx1 " & goto :_3rr0_msg_:

:_write_vbs_:

>"!_vbs_Un_Zipper_!"^
   (
     echo/ ZipFile = "!_zip_File_!" : ExtractTo = "!_Zip_Folder_!\" : Set ObjShell = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
     echo/ Set FilesInZip=ObjShell.NameSpace^(ZipFile^).items: Set FSO = CreateObject^("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
     echo/ ObjShell.NameSpace^(ExtractTo^).CopyHere^(FilesInZip^): Set FSO = Nothing: Set ObjShell = Nothing
   ) && exit /b || set "_msg_err_=Erro: Verifique: "!_Zip_File_!"

:_3rr0_msg_:

if "/!_msg_err_!" == "/" set "_msg_err_= Pasta informada de destino eh invalida^!!" & mode 099,007
color F4 & cls & echo/ & echo/ ERRO^^!! & for /f %%a in ('echo prompt $h ^| cmd')do set "_bs=%%a"
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%a in ('"(cmd /u /c echo=!_msg_err_!) |find /v """')do !_pping! >nul & set/p "=-!_bs!%%a"<nul
!_pping! >nul & set /p "= ^! %_bs%"%_bs% <nul & timeout /t 5 >nul & echo/ & color 0a & exit /b
```

---

> - Código **VBS** sem os **scaping**:

---

```bat
ZipFile = "!_zip_File_!"
ExtractTo = "!_Zip_Folder_!\"
Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set FilesInZip=ObjShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).items
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ObjShell.NameSpace(ExtractTo).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
Set FSO = Nothing: Set ObjShell = Nothing
```

---

---

Comment: Que top! Ficou muito bom sua dica e o código. Desculpa minha ignorância referente o uso do bat, nuca fiz um arquivo `.bat`. Devo por o nome do arquivo `.zip` na linha do código `echo/ ZipFile = "!_zip_File_!"` substituindo pelo nome do meu arquivo sem o `.zip`? Onde eu aponto a caminho do meu arquivo zip?

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!

Comment: @RonisonMatos pode ser passado via commando ou arrasta e solta. Un_Zipper.CMD arquivo.zip com o caminho entre aspas quando tiver espaço no nome do arquivo/pasta.

Comment: Abre o cmd.exe e em seguida chame o Un_Zipper.cmd se não passar nenhum nome de arquivo zip. Você vai receber uma mensagem de ***ERRO*** simulando uma digitação, e contendo informações (pouca).

Comment: Deu certo exatamente como você mencionou! Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você só possa extrair um arquivo dessa forma, pelo CMD, se tiver algum programa que faça isso.

No caso do WinRAR, por exemplo, você pode executar esse comando no seu CMD, para descompactar o arquivo e mandar para o local desejado para extração:

```
C:\Program Files\WinRAR>winrar x C:\temp\seu_arquivo.zip C:\seu_caminho\
```